# DRF use non-model field to verify credentials

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, django-rest-framework

So I have been trying to implement a way to only allow the registration feature of my DRF REST API to be only used by my apps. I know the API can be accessible by anyone, but I thought of requiring client_id and client_secret to the fields so that only the apps registered with my Oauth2 protocol can use it.

I can successfully login using Oauth2 for my apps and access restricted page. I can register with this implementation, but it throws an error that "User object has no attribute client_id".

It makes sense because the client_id is from oauth2, but I only want this field to make sure that it is only being used by my apps.

serializers.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    # Additional fields to verify if allowed to register with client info
    client_id = serializers.CharField(max_length=255)
    client_secret = serializers.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        model = User # for the User model, use get_user_model for custom
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'password', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 
            'client_id', 'client_secret',)
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}
        read_only_fields = ('id',)

    # override create method
    def create(self, validated_data):
        if validated_data['client_id'] != "OI430uPmYGKUJ6h2C7Ohjdn2C9i3WONVMi7WQvu0" and validated_data['client_secret'] != "X8KJNUjIeXf7I8jIbzjt4k92rs6OPxSUqKv9IeaP6YRpLsK8YZVDLK8RcFDqacH4hKSzkuuZET42VyMkIltQt8mUwi16DCGwFWX3fJf7ZxcDMKA6wOQKJnX1GKh9bQ7a":
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Not allowed to do this MATE!")

        user = User.objects.create(
            username=validated_data['username'],
            email=validated_data['email'],
            first_name=validated_data['first_name'],
            last_name=validated_data['last_name']
            )

        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()

        return user
```

I can actually use it to register users, but it throws an error saying that the model doesn't include client_id. I'm not sure how to fix this

I am using oauth2_provider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea of a client id and secret are correct especially when using the OAuth2 authentication/authorization protocol but you're implementing it the wrong way.

First, let me advice that you should pass those into headers as they are authentication credentials just like the Authorization header. That is the common practice. You can either create custom headers for them or add them to the Authorization header. In any case, it shouldn't be handled at the view level but at the authentication level.

Secondly, if you're going to add a non-model field to a model serializer, then you should make sure it is not writable as the serializer would raise errors while building it's fields.

Looking at the [Oauth2_provider docs](https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rest-framework/getting_started.html#step-3-register-an-application), you can see that application authentication with client id and client secret is already implemented.

First, you create an application(your official client app for example). The a client ID and secret are generated for that application. Then when registering a new user, you pass in this token as in the example:

```
curl -X POST -d "grant_type=password&username=<user_name>&password=<password>" -u"<client_id>:<client_secret>" http://localhost:8000/o/token/
```

This will return auth credentials for the user that is unique for that application (or client) and is what is needed for further requests.

If you want to be able to authenticate the application even for unregistered users, just using the application credentials, then you should implement a custom authentication class inheriting from `oauth2_provider.contrib.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication` and add the verification logic there. Don't forget to use the new class as your `DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES` in the REST_FRAMEWORK settings

Comment: Thanks man! The curl example that you gave me, is that for registering new users? Like I use that curl command to log in and get access token. What if there is no username and password for the user yet and want to use oauth2 to make sure they are registering through the app? Sorry I'm pretty new at this

Comment: They will need username and password to register. But if you want to have a case where users can access parts of the app without registering but still be able to authenticate the application, then you can follow the last recommendation I gave. You will need to customize the authentication class to accept custom headers for client id and client secret or accept it through the auth header and authenticate the application, adding the app attribute to the request. You can now use this to check for permissions